# Use "X509 MSP" and "idemix MSP" at the same time

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, x509certificate

I am creating an electronic voting software on the Hyperledger Fabric platform and I need some transactions to be carried out by using ecerts "X509 MSP" and other transactions using "idemix MSP". That is, in some transactions, users must be recognized and in other transactions they must not. I thought about doing two different channels, one that uses "X509 MSP" and the other that uses "idemix MSP", is it possible that both channels communicate with each other? Is there any other better option to implement the above?
I am a bit lost if someone were able to direct me to a solution I would appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 1):

So there is a 1-1 mapping between an MSPID and the MSP provider type.  But an organization can have course have 1 or more MSPIDs.

So for any given organization "N", you could have OrgNMSP1 use X509 and OrgNMSP2 use Identity Mixer.  Both of these can be added to the same channel(s).

A more likely scenario would be to have a single Idemix MSP used by all orgs, but either case will work.